# How to prevent WTL CSplitterWindow resize?

Tags: c++, wtl

I am looking at MFC splitter window class override:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6188/How-to-prevent-resizing-of-views-in-a-splitter-win

I had tested the override source code with WTL CSplitterWindow, but it doesn't worked.

i had modified the MainFrm.h using CSplitOverride instead of CSplitterWindow class.

when program start "api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll missing.." popup error message shows.

windows 7 64bit os platform, 32 bit vs2015 build.

```
class CSplitOverride : public CSplitterWindow
{
public:
  CSplitOverride() { }

protected:
  BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CSplitOverride)
  MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_NCHITTEST, OnNcHitTest)
  END_MSG_MAP()

public:
  LRESULT OnNcHitTest(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
  {
    return HTNOWHERE;
  }
};
```

EDIT: i had been tried thickframe setting but no available. Jan S solution works like that i want.

Comment: The question is not sufficiently accurate. You don't want it to respond to user input? You don't want it to change size when parent is resized?

Comment: what i try to do is video sdk sample application, and main window resize disabled and video frame window should not be resized.

Comment: Looking at dependency walker many of the core windows dlls rely on api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll or another version of it. Your executable shouldn't rely on it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Michael Dunns [excellent tutorial on splitter windows](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4518/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-VII-Splitter-Windows) (this requires a few changes to get it to even compile in vs2013 though!)

[This discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/wtl/discussion/374433/thread/b0192b6a/) on the WTL sourceforge site also may be useful

I think you are asking how you keep a pane a constant size when the main frame is resized? It depends on the alignment of the fixed pane

atlsplit.h defines the following extended styles

```
#define SPLIT_RIGHTALIGNED      0x00000004
#define SPLIT_BOTTOMALIGNED     SPLIT_RIGHTALIGNED
```

As Michael Dun says - "If none of those three styles are specified, the splitter defaults to being left- or top-aligned."

- SPLIT_NONINTERACTIVE stops the user from resizing the pane
- m_cxyMin hard codes the minimum size of the pane specified by the alignment

  m_wndHorzSplit.SetSplitterExtendedStyle(SPLIT_BOTTOMALIGNED | SPLIT_NONINTERACTIVE);
  m_wndHorzSplit.m_cxyMin = 150;

Comment: m_vSplit.SetSplitterExtendedStyle(SPLIT_NONINTERACTIVE); works like charm!